# Why content_for html is not rendered in page.html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I am trying to test a selector that is rendered within content_for in the view of visited controller action.

What I've noticed is that when I debug page.html, I don't see the content that is rendered into yields via content_for, instead, I see only the html that is originally in the application.html.haml.

Is it a matter of waiting for page to get fully loaded ?
I am using:
let(:page_view) { Capybara::Node::Simple.new(@response.body) }

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have into you class

```
render_views
```